# How to tell if your head is detached in git?

Tags: git, version-control, branch

How do you tell if your head has been detached in git? I have a feeling that might be the root of my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
git branch
```

would show

```
* (no branch)
  master
  develop
```

If you are in detached state.

Comment: * master
is attached then?

Comment: Yep, it means you're on master.

Answer (score 27):

An alternative useful for scripts, without having to deal with `$GITDIR` is

```
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic-full-name HEAD
```

This gives me `HEAD` for a detached head, or the branch name on the other case.

Comment: Thanks for supplying the programmatically unambiguous answer...

Comment: I wonder what would happen if you name a branch `HEAD` (yes, that’s malicious!), well, git is robust and `git branch HEAD` gives *fatal: 'HEAD' is not a valid branch name.* :-).

Answer (score 6):

For git version 2.22 and above, the command `git branch --show-current` can be used. In case of detached head state, the output will be nothing.

If you want to use it in a script, we can incorporate it with `wc` as follows:

```
git branch --show-current | wc -l
```

This command will return `0` in case of detached head, and `1` in case of a valid branch.

Comment: nit: In one case, it will print "0", and in the other case it will print "1".  In both cases, it returns 0 (unless `wc` has some catastrophic error like a SIGPIPE).  This is important, since return values can be used with `if` statements, but it is slightly more convoluted to use a command's output for branching logic.

Answer (score 4):

`git status` is supposed to tell you everything relevant.

manually you can look content of .git/HEAD file. If it has a hash, you're detached. if there is a ref like `ref: refs/heads/master` you're not.